# Does full-duplex Ethernet between two computers have unbounded latency?

Tags: networking, ethernet

In school I learned that Ethernet networks have unbounded latency, in the sense that a frame that is ultimately successfully transmitted might be delayed an arbitrarily long time by successive collisions and retransmissions. I am having trouble finding a citation for this fact now, though it is mentioned in [these slides on real-time networking](https://www.ll.mit.edu/HPEC/agendas/proc08/Day2/21-Blau-Presentation.pdf).

My question is whether a full-duplex, 2-host Ethernet network suffers the same issue. The reason that I suspect full-duplex mode may behave differently is that there is no longer the possibility of collision. However there may be other factors that I have not considered.

Comment: what you are learning about is old school CSMA/CD + frozen garden hose networking, on a bus topology. Its a good starting point, but networks haven't worked like that in more than 20 years. Switched networking + Full dup + microsegmented architechure => essentially no collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, full-duplex Ethernet doesn't have collisions, so it always has immediate, exclusive access to the medium, so its latency time is only the time it takes to transmit the frame (e.g. 1522 Byte max frame length / 1 Gbps ≈ 12µsec frame transmission time).

Also note that since Gigabit Ethernet doesn't allow hubs, and old 10 or 100-mbit hubs are almost non-existent nowadays (everyone has switches, even little 5- and 8-port boxes are usually switches), pretty much all Ethernet is full-duplex nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have collisions and full duplex at the same time. They can't co-exist.

A. Hub based network (shared medium), only half duplex, has collisions

B. Switch based network, full duplex possible, no collisions to worry about